# Creating fake data using Faker library Python

Tags: random, faker

Is there a way to create fake data other than the "providers" included in Faker library? For instance, can I generate "First name", "Last name", "Register numbers", "Score on Math exam", "Score on Physics exam", etc.?

Comment: If a provider doesn't do what you want you could create your own. In addition to ones that come bundled, there are contributed [community providers](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/communityproviders.html)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my question.  How do I create my own fake data other than the ones "standard providers" or "community providers" have?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/joke2k/faker#how-to-create-a-provider) for creating a provider. You could look at examples from [here](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/tree/master/faker/providers) to see how to write one. Looking at a few of the source files, it seems to range from almost trivial to fairly involved, depending on what you want the provider to provide.